# Movement of a random walk in the limit (a particle in diffusion)

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, parabolic-pde, brownian-motion, physics

I asked this question in Math Exchange and obtained no answer.

Let $X(t)$ be a stochastic process in time such that $X(0)=0$ and, at each increment of time $\Delta t$, it can move $h$ units in space or not move:
$$ X(t+\Delta t)=\begin{cases} X(t)+h &\text{ with probability $d/2$}, \\
X(t) &\text{ with probability $1-d$}, \\
X(t)-h &\text{ with probability $d/2$}, \end{cases} $$
where $0<d\leq 1$.

I was told and proved the following claim: the net expected displacement is not proportional to the elapsed time but to its square root.

Proof: Let $u(x,t)=\text{Pr}(X(t)=x)$. By the Total Probability Theorem,
$$ u(x,t+\Delta t)=\frac{d}{2} u(x-h,t)+(1-d)u(x,t)+\frac{d}{2}u(x+h,t).\quad (1) $$
This may be written as
$$ \frac{u(x,t+\Delta t)-u(x,t)}{\Delta t}=\frac{d h^2}{2\Delta t}\frac{u(x+h,t)-2u(x,t)+u(x-h,t)}{h^2}. \quad (2) $$
Put 
$$ \frac{dh^2}{2\Delta t}=D. \quad (3) $$
Letting $h\rightarrow0$, we arrive at $u_t=Du_{xx}$, with initial condition $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$. Taking Fourier transforms in the PDE (recall $\hat{\delta}=1$), one obtains
$$ u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right).\quad (4)$$
Using this density function, we may compute 
$$ \overline{x^2}=\int_\mathbb{R} x^2 u(x,t) dx=2Dt.$$
Thus, the square of the displacement is proportional to $t$, as wanted.

**Questions**:

1. The relation $(3)$ between space and time that one imposes so that $(2)$ has a limit is precisely what we want to prove!!! I mean, what happens here? Is this correct, or is there another more formal proof and this proof is just intuitive?
2. The step in which $u(x,t)$ becomes a density function from a mass probability function is not clear. A possible solution could be as follows: we may extend $u(x,t)=u_h(x,t)$ to a step function $\tilde{u}_h(x,t)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ being constant at each interval $](2k-1)/2\cdot h,(2k+1)/2\cdot h[$, and define $\bar{u}_h(x,t)=\tilde{u}_h(x,t)/h$. Then $\bar{u}_h(x,t)$ is a density and satisfies $(2)$. Of course, when $h\rightarrow0$, we need to assume that $\bar{u}_h(x,t)$ tends to a density function, say $p(x,t)$, and that the double limit in (2) concerning $\bar{u}_h(x,t)$ and its partial derivatives converges to the partial derivatives of $p$, so that $p_t=Dp_{xx}$. I do not see this final fact.
3. When solving $u_t=Du_{xx}$, $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$, I understand the formal procedure of taking Fourier transforms. How can one show that $(4)$ is the unique solution we are looking for? I read in the book *Partial Differential Equation in Action*, by Sandro Salsa, that $(4)$ is the unique density function solving $u_t=Du_{xx}$ being radial and self-similar. Imposing the radial condition seems clear, as the particle moves right and left equally. I assume self-similarity comes from the fact that, intuitively, $u(x,t)$ should have a bell shape, as being near $0$ is more probable, so at every $t$, $u(x,t)$ has a similar shape. Is this correct? Thus, the condition $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$ is not used, right? In fact, in the book, the delta function is introduced after obtaining the function given by $(4)$.

Comment: The process $X$ is either incorrectly defined or not used correctly according to its definition.  In particular, is $\Delta t$ in the definition of $X$ fixed?  If so, then why are you allowed to pass to a (distinguished) limit as $\Delta t \to 0$ in the proof of the claim: "the net expected displacement [of $X$] is not proportional to the elapsed time but to its square root."  Given this ambiguity, it is unclear what is being asked, and maybe that is why this question (asked on SE on Jan 10th) did not get answered yet.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I have been taught this in a mathematical physics course. I know that this is not rigorous, but I would like some insight on why this reasoning is frequently used. For instance, in page 47 in the book by Sandro Salsa I mentioned, similar methods to define (at least intuitivelly) the Brownian motion are used: a stochastic process with a discretization $h$ in space and $\Delta t$ in time is defined, and putting a condition on $h$ and $\Delta t$, in the limit one obtains a density function that satisfies a PDE. One goes from a mass to a density function with no further comment...

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Some examples: [http://nebula.physics.uakron.edu/dept/faculty/jutta/modeling/diff_eqn.pdf](http://nebula.physics.uakron.edu/dept/faculty/jutta/modeling/diff_eqn.pdf) and Chapter 2 in [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08292.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.08292.pdf) (this chapter deals with the fractional laplacian from a probabilistic point of view).